# YA book with a child going back in time; the title contains a date

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a Young Adult science fiction book from in the 80's. It had a month and date in title, something like “Thursday the 5th of October”.

A kid somehow goes back in time. He winds up with cavemen. He lives there with what seems forever adapting to their ways then somehow gets back to present time only to find out they were gone only for a few hours. The caveperson chops off a finger.

Answer (score 10):

"[Saturday, the Twelfth of October](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1720070.Saturday_the_Twelfth_of_October)" by Norma Fox Mazer.

[image: Saturday, the Twelfth of October]

He is removing a finger with a sharp stone and wants to borrow her knife.

Per reviewer "[holly](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1720070.Saturday_the_Twelfth_of_October)";

> *There's a bit where Zan watches as the tribal elder cuts off her
>   friend's finger with a rock--I think it was part of the rite of
>   passage thing. Still sticks with me.*